# Facebook comments analyzing

Tags: r, text-mining

Hi I am trying to analyse Facebook comments using r so when I am browsing through the codes I came across one code can anyone explain me clearly what is it

I got the comments after that to clean the comments the code was written as below

```
sapply(comments, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x),sub="byte"))
```

Can anyone explain me what is function doing ?

Comment: Tell us what `comments` looks like.  Basically, it is applying `iconv(enc2utf8(x),sub="byte")` to every comment, where a given comment is `x`.  Then, it is rolling up the result into another vector which gets returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sapply` is designed to recursively apply the function in 2nd position to the element in first position.

This is a shortcut of the apply function. To know more about the apply family, check https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html

`comment` is the element on which the function is applied.

`function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x),sub="byte")` is a function that converts characters between encoding.

`iconv(enc2utf8(x),sub="byte")` does the encoding converting.

`enc2utf8(x)` sets the encoding.

In this case, this is an anonymous function, meaning that you call it "on the fly", without having to name it.

You could also have written this code :

```
a_function <- function(x) {
    iconv(enc2utf8(x),sub="byte")
}

sapply(comments, a_function)
```

Best,

Colin

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I didn't understand what is meant by enc2utf8 and sub="byte" can you explain me this

Comment: enc2utf8 encodes to utf-8. "byte" is the metric the conversion is based upon.